# Find the rate of change of main dependent variable

Tags: calculus, periodic-functions

We have $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\:f(x)=x^2+x\sin(x)$, and we need to find intervals of monotonicity.
Here is all my steps:

$f'(x)=2x+x\cos(x)+\sin(x)$

$f'(x)=0 \Rightarrow x=0$ the only solution.

Now I need to find where $f'$ is positive and negative. I don't want to put value for $f'$ to find the sign, I want another method. So I tried to differentiate the function again to see if $f'$ is increasing or decreasing: $f''(x)=2-x\sin(x) + \cos(x)$ , but I don't know if $f''(x)\geq0$ or $f''(x)\leq0$.

> How can I find the sign for $f'$ to determine monotony of $f$ ?

Comment: Just calculate $f'(1)$ and see what the sign is...

Comment: yeah, another method exists?

Comment: Why would you want another method? Calculating $f'$ at one particular point is about as simple as it gets...

Answer (score 1):

You know that the function $f'(x)$ is a continuous function with only one root. This means that the sign of the function is the same on $[0,\infty)$, and this means that no matter what value of $x>0$ you take, you will find the sign of $f'(x)$ on this interval.

In some cases, it's good to take a particular value since that makes it easier. In your case, it's very easy to calculate $f'(2\pi),$ for example.

Also, you can try to see what the limit of $f'(x)$ is when $x$ becomes large. If the limit is positive (or if it is $\infty$), then the sign of $f'$ is also positive on $[0,\infty)$. In your case, the limit is easy to calculate.

Comment: 5xum we can solve it, if we know that $cos$ is an even function and $sin$ is odd function?

Comment: @Lucas Solve what?

Comment: I mean to find the intervals where the main function is increasing or decreasing

Comment: @Lucas Yes, if you read my answer, you would see that the intervals are $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$, and that in order to see the sign of $f'$ on $[0,\infty)$, you simply need to calculate $f'(x)$ for a particular value of $x>0$. For example, $f'(2\pi)$.

Comment: I think we know the sign for $x>0$ we don't need to calculate $f'$ for $x<0$ because the sign will be opposed

Comment: @Lucas Not really. For example, what if $f(x) = x^3$? Then $f'(x)=3x^2$ which has one root, i.e. $f'(0)=0$. Still, the sign of $f'$ is $+$ on $(-\infty, 0)$ and on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: So in our case we don't need to put a particular value for $x<0$ because: $cos(x)$ is an even function ( for only root the sign is + ) and $sin(x)$ is an odd function, but $x$ is an odd function in front of $cos(x)$, so I suppose if the sign we'll be $-$ for $x\in (-\infty,0]\Rightarrow  x\cos(x)\leq0$, I've right? $x\cdot cos (x)= -\cdot + = -$ for $x\in (-\infty,0]$